# How to create a hyperlink in excel to open word file in specific page by python

Tags: python, excel, hyperlink, ms-word, xlsxwriter

Here is a document(word file), and I extract some sentences from that and write into an excel file by python.

And now I want to create a hyperlink of a sentences, which links to the page where the sentences belong.

For example, if there a sentence "I love python" is in page 5 in a word file, and after I extract this sentence to a cell of an excel file by python, it is possible to create a hyperlink linking back to page 5 of that word file by xlsxwriter?

Answer (score 0):

I afraid there is no way you can hyperlink to a page in DOCS file. You can hyperlink till file level.

Attaching the code here.

```
formula = 'HYPERLINK("[{path]", "Click Here")'.format(path=<PATH TO FILE>)
value = xlwt.Formula(formula)
```

This is done by xlwt library.
Also, The Hyperlink works differently on different excel formats. ie Hyperlink works on Microsoft excel will not work in Open Office Excel.